# Does ordering in Sequelize default to 'updateAt'? Can I have "no" Ordering?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Newbie to web development here - using a postgres db, with Sequelize.

So I have a model called "Form" that `hasMany` of a model called "Section".

When I create a Form, 4 associated sections are created and associated with the Form.

I'm using the following association method of `Form.getSections` to successfully retrieve an array of sections.

When I edit a Section however, the order of the item in the table changes, so when I `Form.getSections` again, the Section I edited is the last item in the array. It appears that by default, Sequelize does `order: [['updatedAt', 'ASC']]` for this method.

My questions are:

1. Is this true?
2. Is there a simple way of stopping this ordering from happening?
3. How do I keep my Sections in place?? Is there such thing as `null` ordering?

Let me know if some actual code will help with this!